# Why Jaxb Unmarshalling is failing with error unexpected element. Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

Hi i am unmarshalling a XML using below code

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SummaryResults.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(
  event -> {
    throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage(),
      event.getLinkedException());
  }
);
SummaryResults summaryResults = (SummaryResults) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new 
StringReader(xml));
```

This is my JAXB Class generated from XSD

```
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"responseHeader"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SummaryResults")
public class SummaryResults {

@XmlElement(name = "ResponseHeader", required = true)
protected SummaryResults.ResponseHeader responseHeader;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
public static class ResponseHeader {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "FileType")
    protected String fileType;
}
}
```

This is my sample xml

```
<SummaryResults>
<ResponseHeader>
<FileType>CFF</FileType>
 </ResponseHeader>
</SummaryResults>
```

But when run my application i am getting an error as

```
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"FileType"). Expected elements are (none)
```

How to fix the issue ?

Comment: Where did the sample XML come from?   Your XSD generated an attribute 
    `@XmlAttribute(name = "FileType")`  but you have an element <FileType> in your sample payload?

Comment: yes my XSD generated the class with @XmlAttribute(name = "FileType") . The XSD shared from one of the service provider and xml is the response of their service .

Comment: You probably need to ask the service provider to clarify why there is an apparent mismatch between the XSD you are using and the related XML - as they do not appear to be compatible. `<FileType>` is clearly an element, but the XSD _apparently_ expects it to be an attribute. (You could generate a new XSD, I suppose - but your small XML sample may not be sufficient to do that reliably.)

Comment: Please add it as answer . I modified the xsd and its working now.

Comment: Changing the xsd isn't the answer (if that is provided). You should change your XML to match the schema. `FileType` is an attribute on `ResponseHeader` so it should be something like `<ResponseHeader FileType="CFF" />`